# WSO2 BPS(BPEL) - Deadline or Escalation expression

Tags: bpel, wso2, apache-ode, wso2-esb

Hi I am working on WSO2 BPS(BPEL) 3.1.0,

@My Scenario

if task is not completed within the given time.

I need to give the deadlines,and escalated to superior  wise.

I tried working examples, but i didn't get any information.

How can i achieve this using WSO2 BPS(BPEL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escalation support is available with WSO2 BPS. Can you check out the ClaimsApprovalTaskWithDeadline.zip sample available from BPS 3.2.0 which is basically doing a notification based on a deadline.

Regards
Nandika